# SqlServer : Number of 'open' issues on a daily basis

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm getting an error with this query "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near ';'" and have been at it for a few hours now. I'm trying to calculate 'open' issues on given days (ideally between a timeframe but for now just on dates that have entries).

My Data is simplified as:
IssueID, CreationDate, CompletionDate

I'd like to tally open issues which is when Year(CompletionDate)=1900 and they are cumulative while they are open, ie: if yesterday there was 1 issue open and today has 1 issue open as well, then today's count of open is 2.  They should drop off once they are resolved (Year(CompletionDate) <> 1900).  Please help I think i'm close?

```
SELECT
x.created_date,
aOpen + Open_Issue - Resolved_Issue as totopen
from(
    select 
    convert(varchar(10), cast(i.CreationDate as date), 101) as created_date, 
    sum( case when YEAR(i.CompletionDate)='1900' then 1 else 0 end) as aOpen,
    sum( case when YEAR(i.CompletionDate)<>'1900' AND (i.CompletionDate >= 
  i.CreationDate) then 1 else 0 end ) as Open_Issue,
coalesce(tot,0) as Resolved_Issue
    FROM Issues i 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT count(IssueID) as tot, CompletionDate as resolved 
    from Issues where YEAR(CompletionDate)<>'1900' group by CompletionDate, 
    count(IssueID))x
ON i.CreationDate = x.resolved);
```

**UPDATE**
I have this returning output correctly on a daily basis only, as in it is not accounting for previous, still open issues (Legacy_Open_Issue) and adding them.

```
SELECT
created_date,
aOpen_Today + Legacy_Open_Issue - Resolved_Issue as totopen
FROM(
SELECT 
    convert(varchar(10), cast(i.CreationDate as date), 101) as created_date, 
    sum( case when YEAR(i.CompletionDate)=1900 then 1 else 0 end) as aOpen_Today,
    sum( case when (YEAR(i.CompletionDate)<>1900 AND (i.CompletionDate >= i.CreationDate)) then 1 else 0 end ) as Legacy_Open_Issue,
    coalesce(tot,0) as Resolved_Issue
FROM Issues i 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT count(IssueID) as tot, CompletionDate as resolved 
    FROM Issues 
    WHERE YEAR(CompletionDate)<>1900 group by CompletionDate
)x ON  x.resolved = i.CreationDate
GROUP BY convert(varchar(10), cast(i.CreationDate as date), 101), coalesce(tot,0)
) AS y;

My Data is
IssueID CreationDate    CompletionDate
1   1/15/2019   1/1/1900
2   1/16/2019   1/17/2019
3   1/16/2019   1/1/1900
4   1/20/2019   1/21/2019
5   1/28/2019   1/1/1900
6   1/30/2019   1/1/1900


My Output is
created_date    totopen
1/15/2019   1
1/16/2019   2
1/20/2019   1
1/28/2019   1
1/30/2019   1


My Output SHOULD be
created_date    totopen
1/15/2019   1
1/16/2019   3
1/20/2019   3
1/28/2019   3
1/30/2019   4
```

thank you for your help

Comment: You need to alias your derived table.  So something like `ON i.createiondate = x.resolved) t;`.  Additionally, why are you grouping by a count?

Comment: I was getting an error 'Column 'Issues.CreationDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.' when I remove that grouping

Comment: Start thinking about your code. What does year() return? an int. Why do you use a string literal for comparison? In addition, your lack of consistent coding style will eventually bite - either you or someone else. Every table should have an alias and every column reference should use the appropriate alias. Lastly stop cramming everything together - that only makes your code more difficult to read and understand. Formatting is important!

Comment: And lastly, your derived table 'x' is not correct. It ends with your group by clause "group by CompletionDate, count(IssueID)" . You probably did not intend to include count() in your group by clause since that is the aggregate you are computing.

Comment: @SMor, i appreciate your tips, i've been coding for 20yrs, i'm just trying to get a quick query working i'm not trying to impress you with beautiful writing styles...  I find your comment useless and insulting...that was a simple but, yes year returns int.  That is not my issue

Comment: And grouping by CompletionDate seems odd given the first part of the query.

Answer (score 0):

Derived tables require an alias. You need to add "AS {alias}" to the end of your query. You should also format and line break the code for better legibility.

```
SELECT
   x.created_date,
   aOpen + Open_Issue - Resolved_Issue as totopen
from(
    select 
       convert(varchar(10), cast(i.CreationDate as date), 101) as created_date, 
       sum( case when YEAR(i.CompletionDate)=1900 then 1 else 0 end) as aOpen,
       sum( case when YEAR(i.CompletionDate)<>1900 AND (i.CompletionDate >= i.CreationDate) then 1 else 0 end ) as Open_Issue,
       coalesce(tot,0) as Resolved_Issue
    FROM Issues i 
    LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT count(IssueID) as tot, CompletionDate as resolved 
       from Issues
       where YEAR(CompletionDate)<>1900
       group by CompletionDate
    )x ON i.CreationDate = x.resolved
    group by convert(varchar(10), cast(i.CreationDate as date), 101)
) AS y;
```

Also, SO generally doesn't do multiple questions per post. I addressed the error/alias issue, but if you have results issues, you should post a new question with sample data and expected results.

Comment: Thank you..  I added that and am back to an earlier error: 'Msg 144, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause.'   any thoughts?

Comment: I'd also unquote the `1900` values, as YEAR returns an `int`. The way it stands, it's comparing to a string value of 1900.

Comment: Thanks I did that and now get 'Column 'Issues.CreationDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.'

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean  I was responding to your request to get rid of count(issueID).  I'm not asking new questions, I understand what the site is meant for - what is my "new" question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to alias the derived table such as:

```
SELECT
x.created_date,
aOpen + Open_Issue - Resolved_Issue as totopen
from(
    select 
    convert(varchar(10), cast(i.CreationDate as date), 101) as created_date, 
    sum( case when YEAR(i.CompletionDate)='1900' then 1 else 0 end) as aOpen,
    sum( case when YEAR(i.CompletionDate)<>'1900' AND (i.CompletionDate >= 
  i.CreationDate) then 1 else 0 end ) as Open_Issue,
coalesce(tot,0) as Resolved_Issue
    FROM Issues i 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT count(IssueID) as tot, CompletionDate as resolved 
    from Issues where YEAR(CompletionDate)<>'1900' group by CompletionDate, 
    count(IssueID))x
ON i.CreationDate = x.resolved) as DT;
```

Comment: Thank you see earlier answer on same point, i don't want to be redundant so i'm working from that one.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use date ranges and ensure there are no gaps in your output (ie. on dates where no tickets were created), you may want to consider using a Dates fact / reference table like this:

```
Select d.Date
    , count(i.IssueID) as TotalOpen
    , sum(case when DateDiff(DD, d.Date, cast(i.CreationDate as date)) = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as NewOpened
    , sum(case when DateDiff(DD, d.Date, cast(i.CompletionDate as date)) = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as NewClosed
From Dates d
Left join Issues i 
  on d.Date between convert(varchar(10), cast(i.CreationDate as date), 101) and
     case when YEAR(i.CompletionDate)='1900' then d.Date else i.CompletionDate end
Group by d.Date
```

Fill the Dates table with all the dates you'd want to display results for (ie. everyday, weekdays) or use a where clause to filter the date range / pattern.